# How to reduce computation and electricity waste other than successful Blockchain/Bitcoin Miner?

Tags: bitcoin, blockchain, ethereum

In a blockchain (bitcoin, ethereum, etc), new transaction are broadcasted in the network, each node(miner) available in the network collects the transaction into block. All miners collect the transaction and try to solve the puzzle but only one minor will be successful in terms of solving the puzzle, creating a proof of work, brodcasting its proof of work to other Miners, and get rewarded. How taking care happens to avoid the computations of other miners who couldn't solve the puzzle 
so that computation and electricity waste can be reduced. Please clarify if above statement is not fare enough.

Comment: You can just become a better crypto-expert than everyone else who has analysed the algorithm ever, find its weaknesses and crack it. Then feel free to generate all the remaining coins in a couple hours/days for yourself and become very rich. In other words: the hardness of the problem and thus the implied 'wasted' effort provide balance in the ecosystem. It is part of the design.

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is an inherent flaw of Proof of Work. A lot of people are having the same concern as you, especially since the bitcoin network uses more electricity than some countries now, with most of that computation going to waste.

In general, to combat this, research is looking at different ways to provide proof, and so far some interesting concepts have emerged, namely Proof of Stake, Proof of Time, Proof of Space, and probably a few more I'm not aware of. Explaining these is beyond the scope of this answer; you can google more information if you're curious.

Comment: Thanks @jeanluc, your reply further guided me to learn about Proof of space(PoSpace)/Proof of Capacity(PoC), Proof of Time(PoT) and Proof of Burn in addition to Proof of Stake(Pos) and Proof of Work(PoW) in which I limited as of now.